# Как не менять строку после выполнения команды bash

Tags: bash

Делаю вывод любой команды `bash` в файл, после этого делаю вывод следующей команды в этот же файл. Хочу чтобы результат второго вывода записывался в ту же строку, что и первый.

Например: 
`echo 123 > file`
`date >> file`

чтобы в итоге получилось `123 Вт. дек.  8 14:17:39 MSK 2015`

Вывод будет вестись в большом массиве текста, поэтому решение не должно быть универсальным для любой строки в документе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man echo`

```
echo -n "123 " > file
echo -n `date` >> file
```

Answer (score 1):

Ребят есть же printf...

добавили \n вывод на нову строку не добавили идет добавление к строке:

```
~$ printf "hello" > output_file
~$ printf "world" >> output_file
~$ cat output_file
 hello world
```

GNU bash

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf

Answer (score 0):

Можно в одну строку:

```
echo '123 '"`date`" > file
```